# Html5 Websocket and sequential treatment queueing

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, queue, sequential

In a Html5 webapp using websocket, the client can received many messages at any time.

Do you think that there is no risk of websocket message collision ?
Is there really only one thread to process events ?
If not, how can i store these messages on the browser and process them one by one sequentially ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is the WebSocket Protocol RFC, i can't find any clue : http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc6455/?include_text=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSocket uses the TCP protocol which means that messages always arrive in the order they were sent. There is no such thing as a "message collision".

There is only one thread to process events, you can create a background thread called a WebWorker to handle the WebSocket connection (including creating the connection, sending and receiving). But then interacting with the rest of your Javascript, including the DOM, is complicated.

To process the messages assign `socket.onmessage` immediately after creating the socket. The function you assign to `socket.onmessage` will receive the messages in the order they arrive. Look for a WebSocket tutorial to see how.